# curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I'm trying to access the API from internet however getting the error.

Trace of curl

λ curl -v  https://api-tryitout-uat.hdfcbank.com/v1/ganapathi
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 103.120.106.197...

- TCP_NODELAY set
- Connected to api-tryitout-uat.hdfcbank.com (103.120.106.197) port 443 (#0)
- ALPN, offering h2
- ALPN, offering http/1.1
- Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
- successfully set certificate verify locations:
- CAfile: C:/Users/tonmo/Downloads/cmder/vendor/git-for-windows/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
  } [5 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
  } [512 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
  { [87 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
  { [3970 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
  { [333 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
  { [4 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
  } [70 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
  } [1 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  } [16 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
  { [1 bytes data]
- TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
  { [16 bytes data]
- SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
- ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
- Server certificate:
- subject: jurisdictionC=IN; businessCategory=Private Organization; serialNumber=080618; C=IN; ST=Maharashtra; L=Mumbai; O=Hdfc Bank Limited; CN=api-tryitout-uat.hdfcbank.com
- start date: Apr  1 00:00:00 2022 GMT
- expire date: May  2 23:59:59 2023 GMT
- subjectAltName: host "api-tryitout-uat.hdfcbank.com" matched cert's "api-tryitout-uat.hdfcbank.com"
- issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=GeoTrust EV RSA CA 2018
- SSL certificate verify ok.
  } [5 bytes data]

> GET /v1/ganapathi HTTP/1.1
> Host: api-tryitout-uat.hdfcbank.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.61.1
> Accept: */*

- OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
- Closing connection 0
  } [5 bytes data]
  curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10054

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: The TLS handshake is successful but the server then closes the connection after it has read the HTTP request. So it might not just adhere to the API defined by the server - whatever this API is. Check the documentation of the API.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Its just like a hello world api.. Simple 1 way TLS API. Could this error be because of the protocol selection SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol

Comment: *"Could this error be because of the protocol selection SSL connection ..."* - the error is after the successful TLS handshake, so it shouldn't be caused by anything SSL related.

Comment: Ok , the error was fixed after removing the WAF-TRP and SSLO network security device from the path. We  re-configured the WAF and SSLO device and then it worked fine.